# MongoDB Driver C# only deserializes half of the object-keys within object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

The problem I'm experiencing occurs when I load (/deserialize) objects from a MongoDB database using MongoDB Driver 2.10. When I do so, only half of the model-objects - only the even objects for some reason (2nd, 4th, 6th, etc.) - get values in the Channel dictionary in the c# class.

I have a MongoDB collection with user objects. The user objects look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bedfd60502d2c2854d43e6f"),
    "displayName" : "User",
    "channels" : {
        "YouTube" : "userchannel",
        "Facebook" : "userchannel",
        "Instagram" : "userchannel",
        "Twitter" : "userchannel"
    }
}
```

All of the User objects have valid values within the channels object

The collection is loaded by the following code:

```
_userCollection = DatabaseService.GetConnection().GetCollection<User>("users");
```

The user class looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("displayName")]
     public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("channels")]
     public BsonDocument channelsDocument { get; set; }}
```

Finally, when I print the info of every Usermodel object, only half of the Usermodels have channels. If I get the 1st, 3rd etc individually from the collection, they still don't have channel value..

Am I missing something? I have been trying for a couple of hours now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
_userCollection = DatabaseService.GetConnection().GetCollection<User>("users");
```

to:

```
_userCollection = DatabaseService.GetConnection().GetCollection<User>("users")
    .Find(Builders<User>.Filter.Empty).ToList();
```

The following example can be tested on LINQPad (I think it is more readable):

```
void Main()
{
    var context = new MongoContext();
    var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Empty; // Finds all
    //var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, ObjectId.Parse("5bedfd60502d2c2854d43e6f"));
    var users = context.User.Find(filter).ToList();
    users.Dump();
}

public class MongoContext
{
    private static readonly IMongoDatabase Database;
    static MongoContext()
    {
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        IMongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        Database = client.GetDatabase("your_databse_name");
    }

    public IMongoCollection<User> User =>
        Database.GetCollection<User>("your_collection_name");
}
```

Comment: I think same as you. Probably those documents are missing values.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get the error: cannot convert MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition to Linq.expression.expressions..

Comment: @Tijs Can you test on LINQPad? If so I can update my answer to a complete, working code.

Comment: @Mahdi I've honestly never worked with LINQPad before. I will check it out

Comment: @Mahdi it seems that MongoDB doesn't return any values for 'channels' for the odd. Now I removed all data from the database and inserted it again, and for some reason the problem doesn't occur anymore... Besides; thanks for advising LINQPad, I really like it!